# Writing to multiple CSV files from a for-loop

Tags: python, csv, csv-write-stream

I have a `for loop` which get the ticker symbol and another for loop inside which gets stock data. Now i am trying to create csv files which will take the data of stock name from the first for loop and add the stock data inside the CSV file.

```
stock_data = []
with open('Nifty 50 Scrapped data.csv') as csvfile:
    stockticker_data = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ')
    for row in stockticker_data:
        # print(row)
        all_data = []
        for ticker in row:
            stock_data.append(web.get_data_yahoo(ticker, '1/1/2018', '1/1/2019'))
            with open(ticker, 'w') as f:
                f = open(ticker,'w')
                f.write(stock_data)
                f.close()
```

I am getting the following error:

```
    f.write(stock_data)
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not list
```

---

the output for    `print(stock_data)` :

```
[                   High          Low  ...     Volume    Adj Close
Date                                  ...                        
2018-01-01  1165.000000  1138.099976  ...   591349.0  1127.366211
2018-01-02  1150.000000  1134.050049  ...   516171.0  1126.479004
2018-01-03  1149.000000  1135.300049  ...   593809.0  1125.641235
2018-01-04  1178.000000  1145.900024  ...   729965.0  1155.361816
2018-01-05  1192.000000  1167.449951  ...  1151320.0  1168.373901
...                 ...          ...  ...        ...          ...
2018-12-27  1384.750000  1354.300049  ...  2174090.0  1362.613403
2018-12-28  1383.000000  1359.000000  ...  1705033.0  1356.160278
2018-12-31  1378.000000  1367.300049  ...   698593.0  1363.159546
2019-01-01  1379.699951  1358.599976  ...   664707.0  1361.670410
2019-01-02  1386.849976  1361.599976  ...  1233780.0  1373.335693

[248 rows x 6 columns]]
[                   High          Low  ...     Volume    Adj Close
Date                                  ...                        
2018-01-01  1165.000000  1138.099976  ...   591349.0  1127.366211
2018-01-02  1150.000000  1134.050049  ...   516171.0  1126.479004
2018-01-03  1149.000000  1135.300049  ...   593809.0  1125.641235
2018-01-04  1178.000000  1145.900024  ...   729965.0  1155.361816
2018-01-05  1192.000000  1167.449951  ...  1151320.0  1168.373901
...                 ...          ...  ...        ...          ...
2018-12-27  1384.750000  1354.300049  ...  2174090.0  1362.613403
2018-12-28  1383.000000  1359.000000  ...  1705033.0  1356.160278
2018-12-31  1378.000000  1367.300049  ...   698593.0  1363.159546
2019-01-01  1379.699951  1358.599976  ...   664707.0  1361.670410
2019-01-02  1386.849976  1361.599976  ...  1233780.0  1373.335693
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error tells you that the `stock_data` is a `list` and `write()` method expects a `str`. How to solve that knowing that the data returned from `web.get_data_yahoo()` is a `pd.DataFrame`? We can do that using `pd.to_csv` like so:

```
stock_data = []
with open('Nifty 50 Scrapped data.csv') as csvfile:
    stockticker_data = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ')
    for row in stockticker_data:
        # print(row)
        all_data = []
        for ticker in row:
            stock_data.append(web.get_data_yahoo(ticker, '1/1/2018', '1/1/2019'))
            for df in stock_data:
                df.to_csv(ticker, header=None, index=None, sep=' ', mode='a')
```

Comment: `    tmp = ' '.join(stock_data)
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, DataFrame found ` I got the following error. Even if i could keep the DataFrame without it being overwritten every iteration that would also work. I am trying to write stock_data. Thanks

Comment: That happens due to the data returned from `web.get_data_yahoo()`... could you print that for me?

Comment: I have added the output for `print(stock_data) :` above

Comment: I edited my answer after knowing `web.get_data_yahoo()` returns a dataframe

Comment: Thank for you help, i have 1 quick question, what should i be looking at if i want program to remember what data i already have and add the data that is new instead of rewriting everything. Is this what Pickle does?

Comment: `pickle` is a way to save an object as it is. So, you can save `stock_data` in a pickle file using the `dump` function. Now, this file contains the list as it is. If you want it back at any time, you can use `load` to load the list.

Comment: You are right that i can load this list for future analysis but is there a way to code where the program would remember what the last date was and just download the data from that day instead of downloading it from start date. I am willing to learn if you could just point me to the general direction. I really need this because i want to do data analysis thousands of symbols, downloading all that data everyday would cost me a lot of bandwidth and time. A way where the program would look at the last index value and start updating from there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201638/discussion-between-new-coder-and-anwarvic).